# .Net MAUI: Exception TargetInvocation on DisplayAlert

Tags: maui

I'm currently working on my first .NET MAUI application, and I have successfully used DisplayAlert messages on other pages without any issues. However, I encountered a problem when trying to display a DisplayAlert message within the AppShell, where I have set up SignalR using the code provided. When I attempt to include the message in a DisplayAlert, it throws an exception. On the other hand, if I simply use a regular label to display the message, it works fine.

```
 private readonly HubConnection _hubConnection;
    private string baseUrl = "https:/";


    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Disable back button for a specific page
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);

        _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl($"{baseUrl}/notificationhub").Build();
        _hubConnection.On<Notification>("NewCallNotificationReceived", (notify) =>
        {
            ShowPopup(notify.Message);
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
            {
                await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
            });
        });
    }
    private async void ShowPopup(string message)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Title", message, "OK");
    }
```

Comment: what does the stack trace and/or InnerException property show?

Comment: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: that doesn't answer either of my questions.  Please look at the **InnerException** property or the stack trace

Comment: @Jason, 
    private void ShowPopup(string message)
    {
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Notification", message, "OK");
        });
    }
Is partially fixing the issue. Because after while is slowing down the interface but it does work :(

Comment: @Robert You can add "Your Answer" below, with the solution. This helps others with similar problem later.

Answer (score 0):

run it in main thread like the sample below:

```
   MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
        });
```